# Convert Varchar to etl_unixtime in SQL

Tags: sql, date, varchar

I need to convert a VARCHAR field to etl_unixtime value, Can any one please help me?

Comment: And what is `etl_unixtime`? I don't think I have seen it in MS SQL before.

Comment: Its a date format of Unix system to store in SQL